# How to fix error with resource routes definition

Tags: laravel-5, routes

Here https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers I read that defining a resource 
I had post/put methods :

```
POST    /photos store   photos.store
...
PUT/PATCH   /photos/{photo} update  photos.update
```

but defining in routes/web.php next resource routes:

```
Route::resource('site-subscriptions', 'Admin\SiteSubscriptionsController', [ 'except' => [] ] )->middleware('WorkTextString');
```

with form definition :

```
   <form method="POST" action="http://local-votes.com/admin/site-subscriptions/store" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form_site_subscription_edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="X7rzFjRq4o4TeA67FmkQTMI9ApjygM3ovE1C14i2">
```

I got error for POST :

```
  "message": "",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
    "file": "/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/votes/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
    "line": 255,
```

Have I error in my web.php definition error ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with blade, getting a working link this way is bad, you should use laravel helpers like the following:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('site-subscriptions.store')}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form_site_subscription_edit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

this way you are making sure that the links are correct even if you change your APP_URL in the deployment.

what actually done, is calling `route` helper function to get the URL for you by the route's name.

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-route):

> **route()**:
>
> The route function generates a URL for the given named route:
>
> $url = route('routeName');
> If the route accepts parameters, you may pass them as the second argument to the method:
>
> $url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1]);
> By default, the route function generates an absolute URL. If you wish to generate a relative URL, you may pass false as the third argument:
>
> $url = route('routeName', ['id' => 1], false);